# Export javadoc with constant variable value as japanese characters

Tags: java, javadoc

I have a trouble related to exporting javadoc with the constant variable value as Japanese:

For example:

```
/**
 * The Class Constants.
 */
public class Constants {

    /** The Constant HIRAGANA. */
    public static final String HIRAGANA = "HIRAGANA";

    /** The Constant KATAKANA.
     *  values as {@value #KATAKANA} 
     *  */
    public static final String KATAKANA = "片仮名"; 
}
```

I'm trying to export javadoc with options as: 
**-charset "UTF-8" -encoding "UTF-8"**
or 
**-charset "UTF-8" -encoding "UTF-8" -docencoding "UTF-16"**

But the output javadoc for the japanese value constants as: 
 **public static final java.lang.String KATAKANA  "\u7247\u4eee\u540d"**  
for **KATAKANA** String constant

Please help me to explain this situation.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have tested if you write the japanese character direct into the comment then the document will generate correct, but if using the @value then it will generate the code like yours.

Comment: I didn't found any solution.  As my investigation, only source code (without comment) is encoded as UTF-16. So the japanese text does not display same as declaration.